# PHP version problems after homebrew install

Tags: php, homebrew, php-7.4, php-8.1

MacOS 12.1 After successfully installing php 8.1 with homebrew (along with apache/mySQL and phpmyadmin) I am trying unsuccessfully to install/link php 7.4. After following instructions to install, unlink, link, php -v returns 7.4 but phpinfo() shows 8.1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I followed these instructions and it's worked for me: [https://www.markhesketh.com/switching-multiple-php-versions-on-macos/](https://www.markhesketh.com/switching-multiple-php-versions-on-macos/)

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough, using a full name such as "shivammathur/php/php@8.1" for the link command is what worked for me.

Eg:

```
brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Also, don't forget to close your terminal completely and reopen it before checking the version with php -v.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if I never successfully killed the included MacOS Apache. I uninstalled home-brew and the server was still running (with PHP8.1!). Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).